# adding newrelic addon heroku java

Tags: java, heroku, jetty, newrelic, add-on

I'm trying to add the newrelic addon to my application that is deployed in heroku using Jetty.
This is what i'm trying to do and the answer I get. I Already unpack the newrelic folder in the root.

```
~ $ java -jar newrelic/newrelic.jar install
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS:  -Djava.rmi.server.useCodebaseOnly=true -Djava.rmi.server.useCodebaseOnly=true
Jul 16, 2014 03:20:57 +0000 [95 1] com.newrelic INFO: Agent is using Logback    
***** ( ( o))  New Relic Java Agent Installer
***** Installing version 3.8.1 ...
Could not edit start script because:
 .:. Could not locate a Tomcat, Jetty, JBoss, JBoss7 or Glassfish instance in /app
Try re-running the install command with the -s <AppServerRootDirectory> option or from <AppServerRootDirectory>/newrelic.
If that doesn't work, locate and edit the start script manually.
No need to create New Relic configuration file because:
 .:. A config file already exists: /app/newrelic/newrelic.yml
***** Install incomplete
***** Next steps:
For help completing the install,
```

thank you for the help

Comment: Have you tried heroku toolbelt?

Comment: what do you mean explicitly?

Comment: There is a heroku toolbelt which is required to be downloaded and then from cli you can run heroku add commnd to add an addon

Comment: I already add the addon, but the app doesnt send any data to the monitor. So i'm trying to install the agent

Answer (score 0):

What is in /app?  Is that where your dispatcher (e.g. Tomcat, Jetty, JBoss, Glassfish, etc.) is located?  If your dispatcher is *not* in /app you should move the newrelic directory to the same directory as your dispatcher.  As an alternative, you could edit the startup script (catalina.sh, for example) for the dispatcher and provide the fully qualified path to the newrelic.jar. The error message is telling you that the installer attempted to edit the startup script for the dispatcher (see below) and could not find it. If you were using Tomcat, say, then the installer would want to find a catalina.sh file and add a couple of lines to that file. The installer looked in the parent of newrelic (i.e. /app) and didn't find a bin directory which it would have if Tomcat were a child of /app.

Example 1:

Tomcat is in /var/opt/tomcat *and* you want to put newrelic in the same directory. If you then took the newrelic directory and made its path /var/opt/tomcat/newrelic then your command java java -jar newrelic/newrelic.jar install will work because the installer will look in /var/opt/tomcat/bin and see the catalina.sh file which it will edit to put a pointer to the newrelic.jar file.

Example 2:

Tomcat is in /var/opt/tomcat *and* you **do not want** newrelic to be a child of tomcat and instead want it to live in /app/newrelic.  In that case you would edit the catalina.sh file and add the following two lines:

```
NR_JAR=/app/newrelic/newrelic.jar; export NR_JAR
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -javaagent:$NR_JAR"; export JAVA_OPTS
```

Please let me know if you need clarification on any of the above.

Cheers
Adrienne

(New Relic Support)

Comment: I'm using an embedded jetty server in heroku, so I don't know where the dispatcher is located. I already try your solutions but they doesn't work. I don't know how to get the new relic agent work. Always show me the same error.