# Heroku + Java + WAR deployment + New Relic

Tags: java, heroku, war, newrelic

Heroku don't allow to upload files, just git repository(we can't share sources) and WAR files. We using WAR.

So, how i can use(my own newrelic.yml and newrelic-agent.jar) new relic with war deployments on heroku?

**update.**

Ok, i add newrelic add-on to application, and now can set some environment variables:

```
heroku config:set NEW_RELIC_APP_NAME="name"
heroku config:set NEW_RELIC_LICENSE_KEY="key"
```

But it's very basic and **not working :)**. How to pass own config file to add-on?

update.

Find similar question: [Heroku : Using NewRelic with heroku deploy:war approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13105865/heroku-using-newrelic-with-heroku-deploywar-approach)

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to get application monitoring working with New Relic is by using the add-on as described here: https://addons.heroku.com/newrelic

Something like this should work:

```
heroku addons:add newrelic:stark
```

Heroku has some documentation about how to monitor Java applications using New Relic here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/newrelic#java-configuration

There are also some other similar Stack Overflow questions about Heroku, New Relic and Java.  For example:

[adding newrelic addon heroku java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24771713/adding-newrelic-addon-heroku-java)

Answer (score 1):

You can upload a *.war* file to Heroku using either the Heroku toolbelt:

```
heroku plugins:install https://github.com/heroku/heroku-deploy
heroku deploy:war --war <path_to_war_file> --app <app_name>
```

Or directly using curl:

```
curl -X POST -F war=@mywebapp.war -i https://:<API_KEY>@direct-to.herokuapp.com/direct/mywebapp/war
```

Comment: Thank you, but i know how to deploy war, i don't know how to get newrelic working with my config file.

Comment: Oops, sorry about that; I misunderstood your question.